# How to prevent that a part cover another part's place when it closed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have two tab pane on form as MainTab and Console. When I close "MainTab", "Console Tab" cover place of MainTab. I want that console will stay its own place. My example image is here:

[image]

Can anybody give me some advice about it? Thank you.

Comment: Not possible.  Why would you want nothing there?

Comment: Because of design requirements. I think placeHolder can be a solution for this but I could not find how to use it.

Comment: Is this an e4 app using an Application.e4xmi or a 3.x compatibility app?

Comment: It is an e4 app using an Application.e4xmi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your top part is in a Part Stack add the tag `NoAutoCollapse` to the part stack

[image]

Comment: When I did it I take an error : org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This is the standard way to do this used by Eclipse and many of my own apps. You will have to show us the full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, exception was not about tag, I added NoAutoCollapse tag into my part stack and it worked. Thank you.